# VB.net local server database login validation

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, data-retrieval

I created a server-based database from within my project so that my program can directly access data locally. However when I run my program, it can't seem to find the MDF and I get the following error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim rd As SqlDataReader

    con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=true"
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "select AdminID password from Admin where AdminID = '" & txtAdminID.Text & "' and AdminPassowrd = '" & txtPassword.Text & "' "
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If rd.HasRows Then
        Administration.Show()
    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Please re-enter your login credentials")

    End If
```

The table which I am trying to pull data from exists as you can tell here:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure why the program cannot find the MDF as it is located in the main directory.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you set `|DataDirectory|`?

Comment: I was under the assumption that |DataDirectory| is the root folder? Is this not the case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message talks about SQL Server, so the issue may be that you're not using the correct provider to access the MDF file. You're not specifying it, so you're probably getting a default SQL Server oledb provider.

Try to specify in your connection string: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 or Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```